# Android different button size on real device vs emulator

Tags: android, layout, android-emulator, screen

My Android App looks different on a real device (Samsung Galaxy Mini http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_mini_s5570-3725.php ) than on Emulator.

I have the latest SDK, AVD set up for 240x320 LDPI (120ppi)

My layout: I have a vertical linerlayout with 4 items: 4x horizontal linerlayout

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMainLines"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMainLine1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

            ....

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMainLine4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Then from code, I add 10 buttons to all the 4 'LinearLayoutMainLine'
So at the end I have 4x10 buttons on the screen.

```
 Button button = new Button(_context);
 button.setTypeface( Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.BOLD);
 button.setOnClickListener(this);
 button.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
 button.setText(letter);    
 button.setBackgroundResource(id);
....later....
 forall (buttons_line1)
    layout1.addView(button);
....
 forall (buttons_line4)
    layout4.addView(button);
```

Note that, the background image and the text of the buttons are changed from the code time-to-time, they do not remain the same as they were created with.
However, all the used images are same sized (double-checked), and buttons' text is always 1 letter.

**The problem**:

On the emulator: I have 4x10 buttons with size 19x36

On the Mini device: I have 3x10 buttons with size 19x38, and the 4th row is 19x32.
This last row of buttons are shorter thus their texts are cut in the half.

The used images: res\ldpi\button.9.png are all 18x26 sized.

What could cause this difference?

I am attaching a merged screenshot, left is the Device, right is the Emulator.

[image]

By spec, Mini has ~127 ppi, maybe this is the problem? But I cannot set up this for Emulator, as it has fixed list for density, and 120 is the closest. However, there it's fine as I mentioned.

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Post the layout xml file.

Comment: @Squonk, it's quite complex, quite some layouts in layouts, and besides that, these buttons are created from the code, not part of the XML layout.

Comment: Well post the code if that's the case.

Comment: Very simple: `Button button = new Button(_context);` `button.setTypeface( Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.BOLD);`
`button.setOnClickListener(this);`
`button.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);`
`button.setText(letter);`  
`button.setBackgroundResource(id);`
`...and later...`
`layout.addView(button)`

Comment: Not so simple.  How do you set the size?  And please edit your question to post code etc.

Comment: @Simon: question edited with details